# Parse JSON using SQL and Amazon Aurora DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I know there is a way with regular MySQL 5.7 to parse JSON values. But that doesnt seem to work with Aurora.

I have stored in records a field called ppain. Its contents are like this;

```
["Shoulder_Left","Knee_Right","Wrist_Left","Ankle_Right","Back"]
```

So I want to get a count of unique ppain values in my SELECT query.

Answer (score 3):

CORRECTION: AWS RDS supports MySQL 5.7 but not Aurora... (however AWS do say they're actively working on it).

UPDATE:
AWS <s>Aurora</s> RDS now supports MySQL 5.7 (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-update-support-for-mysql-5-7/)

---

If I'm not mistaken Aurora is (currently) based on MySQL 5.6...

Comment: Yup. So I can't use the new JSON stuff

Comment: The update that says AWS Aurora now supports MySQL 5.7 is incorrect - the link points to the blog post that announces that RDS MySQL now supports MySQL 5.7. RDS Aurora and RDS MySQL are not the same thing and RDS Aurora is MySQL 5.6 compatible, NOT MySQL 5.7 compatible (https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/details/).

Comment: For those using MySql on Aurora - Aurora 2.10.1 clusters support JSON_ARRAYAGG.